# Summing times based on date criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
  Col A       Col J   Col K   Col L
8/1/2015       0:58     10     4:31
8/1/2015       0:19      1     3:56
```

Can I automate a function or set of functions to look up information out of this data set based on the date in column A?  I'm currently doing this by hand:

```
=((L24+L25)-(J24+J25))/(K24+K25)
```

I and am wondering if there is anything that could make this easier.  I've tried sumif's, sumproducts, nested if/index-match statements but have run out of ideas or am just not writing the functions properly.

Comment: I'm unclear on how that maths equation related to the date in column A

Comment: I'm trying to associate the equation with the dates in column A.  For instance, if column A = 8/1/2015 then retrieve all associated column L values and sum, subtract summed column J values and then divide by sum of values in column K.

Comment: You mean like `=(sumif(A:A, date(2015, 8, 1), L:L)-sumif(A:A, date(2015, 8, 1), J:J))/sumif(A:A, date(2015, 8, 1), K:K)` ? (-0.027146465
 for the above data)

Comment: I copied your example directly into my spreadsheet and got 0:00:00 as a value, it also told me there's a circular reference in the formula if that means anything, I'm pretty sure it doesn't.  I also anchored the ranges to 24 through 100 for the references and it still gave me 0's for a time value.  This is what I'm looking for though, it's just not giving me the results I need.

the value for the above information should return as 0:39:05.

Comment: btw, the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) might tighten that up but you should NOT use full column references.

Comment: The circular ref causes the zero value. You put the formula into either column A, J, K or L and a formula should not reference itself.

Comment: Wish I could post the spreadsheet I'm working with... too new to add pic's or files yet!  So I tried to input the anchored formula into the A, J, K and L columns to no avail.

=(SUMIF($A$24:$A$100,DATE(2015,8,1),$L$24:$L$100)-SUMIF($A$24:$A$100,DATE(2015,8,1),$J$24:$J$100))/SUMIF($A$24:$A$100,DATE(2015,8,1),$K$24:$K$100)

This is how I've modified it thus far but even with the anchoring it's still not producing a time value

Comment: a) your formula as provided above gives me the same negative answer. b) post a redacted copy of the worksheet to a public file upload area like One Drive, Google Drive or DropBox and post the link back here.

Comment: You're right, the column references are backwards in my original post.... damn I feel retarded.  J should be the lower value and L the higher.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_qaX_uTpWznRmNNZWtyZ1JJYzQ 

nothing in the spreadsheet needs to be redacted as there's no sensitive patient info in this workbook.

Comment: `=(SUMIF($A$24:$A$100, DATE(2015,8,1), $L$24:$L$100)-SUMIF($A$24:$A$100, DATE(2015,8,1), $J$24:$J$100))/SUMIF($A$24:$A$100, DATE(2015,8,1), $K$24:$K$100)`

Comment: I still can't tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qaX_uTpWznRmNNZWtyZ1JJYzQ/view?usp=sharing  did that work?

Comment: Go it now. Please hold...

Comment: basically i'm trying to get excel to seek all values in columns J, K and L based on the date value in column A.  so if(A:A="8/1/2015" then(for all instances of 8/1/2015) (sum(values of L)-sum(values of J))/sum(values of K).

Comment: On what worksheet? The one it opened to doesn't have an sample data

Comment: any of the unit worksheets:  2 core, 1 tower, 9 tower

Comment: OK, the formula I supplied above works perfectly. The problem is that the times in your data are not times, they are text that looks like a time. You need to run Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish on each of these to get them to be true times. They will right align when they are true time. I have a macro sub routine somewhere that will do the whole workbook if you like. (The formula above is he one that starts `=(SUMIF($A$24:$A$100, DATE(2015,8,1),...`

Comment: See G15:Q15 in **1 Tower** [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Unit%20Report%20Cards.xlsx).

Comment: Wow!  You're amazing!  I'd love the subroutine if you could find it... if it's not too much trouble!  :)  This just made my day 1000x simpler!

Comment: make sure to add your answer to the list, i provided a holding answer just in case, but feel free to make your own answer so i can accept it and give you the credit! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should pick up the results you are looking for.

```
=(SUMIF($A$24:$A$100,G16, $L$24:$L$100)-SUMIF($A$24:$A$100,G16, $J$24:$J$100))/SUMIF($A$24:$A$100, G16, $K$24:$K$100)
```

There is another problem where the times are actually text-that-look-like-time. The first indication of this is their left-alignment in the cells. A quick run through Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, Finish will revert each column to actual times but each column needs to have that run on it individually.

The following is a routine that will quickly run through each worksheet and perform the action on each column.

```
Sub fix_text_times()
    Dim w As Long, c As Long, fndMrg As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = True

    For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(w)
            With .UsedRange.Cells
                Set fndMrg = .Cells.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)
                Do While Not fndMrg Is Nothing
                    fndMrg.MergeCells = False
                    Set fndMrg = .Cells.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)
                Loop

                For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, c), _
                                DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
                Next c
            End With

        End With
    Next w

    Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = False

End Sub
```

The [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) does not play well with merged cells so I have unmerged any that I could find. I balanced this action against all of the multiple [Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174786%28v=office.11%29.aspx) found in Master Input 1 and figured that you could put them back if you desparately wanted them.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  If i could give you Reddit Gold I would! :)